# Easy recreation of "Shared, Desktop Private on 1st use" views

Tags: view, lotus-notes

I have some views that uses @UserName in the selection formula. For working that, the view must be "Shared, Desktop Private on 1st use". That is no problem.

But this views are going to be redesigned quiet often.

As this is a bunch of views it is very uncomfortable for the user to delete each of this views to recreate from scratch with design changes.

I try different things to get that done with an agent but no one is fool-proof and give some strange results (sometimes even do not update the design).

Best result so far is to delete the icon from the workspace and open the application again. That works (until now) always. But this is so annoying for end users to reopen the app from the (deep leveled) server folders.

Any other method to update the design of "private on 1st use" views ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to solve the same problem and ended up doing two things - (1) automatically send the user an email with a link to the database and ask them to remove the database icon so that the private views get deleted and (2) alert the user when the design of a private view has changed.

The first part was fairly simple - I wrote a LotusScript function that would send the current user an email message containing a link to the current database (the one that contains the private views), along with some meaningful text and database information. All the user had to do then was exit the database, remove the database icon, open the email they just received and open the database again using the link. No need to navigate the server folders or wonder which server to go to. This can be used on its own, e.g. in a button, but I ended up combining it with something a little more tricky.

The second part was devising a way to alert the user that the design of the view they are opening is outdated. The tricky part was detecting that the design of the view has changed. What made this possible was what actually caused the problem in the first place - the fact that Notes caches the private view. When caching the private view, Notes also caches constants that the script in the view events refer to, that are part of LotusScript libraries the view uses.

Here's a description of the design I used:

- Let the view use shared script library, `PrivateViewsCode`.
- In `PrivateViewsCode`'s `(Declarations)` declare `Const DESIGN_VERSION = "1.0"`.
- In `PrivateViewsCode` declare function `myQueryopen`. One of the parameters `myQueryopen` receives is string `designVersion`.
- In the private view's `Queryopen` event call `myQueryopen`, passing `DESIGN_VERSION` to `designVersion`. Since this code is in the view that is cached, `DESIGN_VERSION` will contain the constant value as it were in the moment the view design was cached (when the user first opened it), in this case - `"1.0"`.
- In `myQueryopen` compare `designVersion` to `DESIGN_VERSION`.

  ```
  Dim designChanged As Integer  
  designChanged = (designVersion <> DESIGN_VERSION)
  ```

  Since `myQueryopen` is part of `PrivateViewsCode` script library, here you actually compare the `DESIGN_VERSION` (as cached in the private view and then passed to `myQueryopen`) to `DESIGN_VERSION` from `PrivateViewsCode`, which is always current.
- The only thing left is to be sure to recompile the views (Tools\Recompile all LotusScript) after changing `DESIGN_VERSION`.

I hope this explains the design, here is how it works:

- After making changes to private views design you change the version:

  ```
  DESIGN_VERSION = "1.1"
  ```
- Recompile all LotusScript.
- Refresh the database design.
- Users open any private view that uses this functionality.
- They get a message saying they will receive link to the database and that they have to remove the icon from the workspace and open it again using the provided link.
- The user closes the database and removes the icon - private views are deleted.
- The user opens the database link in the email, the next time they open one of the private views, the new design is cached along with the new value of `DESIGN_VERSION` (here, `"1.1"`).
- The comparison `(designVersion <> DESIGN_VERSION)` now yields `false`. Everything is back to normal until the next update.

Ken's way of handling this has the major advantage of not involving the users at all. This wasn't an option for me because of the frequency with which I made changes to the views (the application was just deployed and I had many requests for changes to the views) as well as the big number of private views in the application.

(Edit)
I assumed you had a specific reason to use private views, but I used the "Show Single Category" in an embedded view (just as leyrer suggests) ever since it became available and was quite happy with it. If you see any limitations to using the "Show Single Category" option, I'll try to help you with that.

Answer (score 4):

As you noticed, private views are a pain to maintain. Why not go a different way to solve your problem?

Create a categorized view, where the first, categorized column contains the field you compare the username in your current solution to.
Than embed that view into a form as a "single category embedded view" and use @username as the category.

Presto. Now you have a view that only shows documents for the current user and you can change the design whenever you like.

Mick Moignard has a good article on that topic online: [Dynamic view filtering in Notes](http://www.dominopower.com/issues/issue200604/00001755001.html).

See also the Lotus Domino Designer Help, Topic "[To show a single category in embedded views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SHOW_SINGLE_CATEGORY_IN_EMBEDDED_VIEWS_OVER.html)"

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that moves the pain from the end user to the developer.  I designed the navigation to use outlines so I can control where the user goes when they navigate to a view.  Notes outline entries can be changed without the user needing to go through the delete-icon-then-reopen-database hassle.

When I need to update the design of the private view, I rename it as well and also update the reference to it in the notes outline entry.  At the users desktop, when they next open the database, a new private view will be created for them.  Most (or all) of my users never noticed anything, at least they never mentioned it!

The process is fairly easy for the developed but also fairly easy to forget.  Also, the user's workspace will end up having a lot of references to old unused private views, which if they are large in size might become a problem down the line.  If you change the view twenty times, or change twenty views, for example, it may be time to delete the icon to clear them out.  For me the changes were rare enough for this not to matter.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your dilemma is not too hard to solve, but a little tedious. There is a [technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21086960) on simply removing private views programmatically. It is a common design issue for developers.

I have had to take the following approach to manage multiple private views which were all going through multiple versions at any one time.

The secret is to do a check on the DatabaseOpen event, as it's a view held on the local client so you need to do this through user's UI activity. As long as your Lotus Notes client fleet is at running version 6.5.x you could try the following. To be concise, I have outlined what you need to do.

1. Name your private view "yourPrivateViewName_1.0|yourPrivateViewName"

   - Note the use of an alias. This is so you can reference the view in an outline or code, no matter how many versions you use.
   - This can also be a multi-valued field if you have more than one private view to manage.
2. Create a database profile document that has a field with the current private view name, eg "youPrivateViewName_1.1"
3. On DatabaseOpen loop through the views, finding the private view(s) then compare the name to the one in the database profile. The naming convention is designed to make it possible to do a version check. If the versions don't match, remove the view. When the user opens that view the next time it should grab the current version you have released.

There are other ways as well, like checking the timestamps on the private view and the template, but it still requires a way to single out the private view. But I found this way easy enough to manage.

Comment: Two disadvantages to consider if using this approach are (1) it won't work for local replicas of the database and (2) the delay when opening the database may be noticeable (it takes some time to loop through the views).

Comment: @Hristo. What component would not work for local replicas ? I agree that looping through the views on Database open can have an adverse affect on user performance if you have 100's of views. I usually keep the required views to a minimum. It's all relative to the developers system they have to build.

Comment: When I worked on this I ran into the limitation that, as noted in the technote you link to, "It is not possible to remove private views that are stored in the desktop.dsk database.". Private views get stored in desktop.dsk if (1) the database is local or (2) for a server-based database the user is not allowed to "Create personal folders/views" (in which case the user can open "private on first use" view, but instead of on the server the private view is stored locally in desktop.dsk on the user's machine). So I had to resort to removing the database icon instead.

Comment: @Hristo. I had read it slightly differently as it was trying indicate that you should not try and remove the original design element. But I see what you mean. My scenario's the user was able to create server based private views. So, some caveats apply.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all !

I finally ended up with the following:

Create an Agent running from menus that close the database

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    s.SetEnvironmentVar "remove-"+s.CurrentDatabase.ReplicaID,"1"
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    ws.CurrentDatabase.Close
End Sub
```

In the database close event mail a database link and send keys to remove from workspace

```
Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (Byval bVk As Integer, Byval
 bScan As Integer, Byval dwFlags As Integer,Byval dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Sub Queryclose(Source As Notesuidatabase, Continue As Variant)

    Dim s As New NotesSession
    x = s.GetEnvironmentString("remove-"+s.CurrentDatabase.ReplicaID)
    s.SetEnvironmentVar "remove-"+s.CurrentDatabase.ReplicaID,""
    If x="" Then Exit Sub

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Call ws.AddDatabase( s.CurrentDatabase.Server,s.CurrentDatabase.FilePath)

    Dim m As New NotesDocument(s.CurrentDatabase)

    m.From = s.CurrentDatabase.Title
    m.SendTo = s.CommonUserName
    m.Subject = "Link to open " + s.CurrentDatabase.Title

    Dim rt As New NotesRichTextItem(m,"Body")
    rt.AppendText s.CurrentDatabase.Title
    rt.AppendText " -> "
    rt.AppendDocLink s.CurrentDatabase,"Open Application"

    m.Send False
    Delete m

    keybd_event &h2e,0,0,0 ' Del key down
    keybd_event &h2e,0,2,0 ' Del key up
    keybd_event &h0D,0,0,0 ' Y key down
    keybd_event &h0D,0,2,0 ' Y key up

End Sub
```

(You all got your upvotes but a i mark as answer for the lowest rep. points user.)

Answer (score 0):

Since Domino has been sold by IBM to HCL, IBM has deleted the Domino content.

Luckily, HCL has posted an article about this: [How to manage or remove Personal Views and Personal Folders on the Administrator side](https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0100180)

It lists both a method to check for and remove the Private views manually as a LotusScript approach using a server agent.  I have adapted this to an agent I run on design changes as needed.

Addendum to issue [Hristo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631889/hristo) raised about constants: A liittle know fact is that a LotusScript Library can have a Property, like so:

```
%REM
    Property Get Design_Version
    
    return the design version of this Library
%END REM
Property Get Design_Version As String
    Design_Version = "1.2"
End Property ' Get Design_Version
```

This avoids the Const cache problem.

Note that module level Property routines are Private by default, which is good.

While implementing a Designer cleanup agent, I got an idea which also works when this routine is called from the Initialize sub in the Database script, which is run on Database open if it has code:

```
%REM
    Database Script Database Script
    Created Sep 20, 2023 by Lars Berntrop-Bos/SKG
    
%END REM
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
    Call CleanUpPrivateOn1stUseViews
End Sub
%REM
    Sub CleanUpPrivateOn1stUseViews
    
%END REM
Sub CleanUpPrivateOn1stUseViews
    Const proc = "dbScript::CleanUpPrivateOn1stUseViews"
    ' If noDebug Then On Error GoTo bublUp
    
    Dim masterViews List As String ' key = title, value = nid
    Dim nidMasterViews List As String ' key = nid, value = title
    Dim nidMasterLastModified List As Variant ' key = nid, value = LastModified
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim nid As String
    Dim nidNext As String
    Dim title As String
    Dim flags As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Print "Running Private on 1st use View copy Clean Up"
    
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    
    '-- Create a note collection only for Private on 1st use masters 
    Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
    nc.SelectViews = True
    nc.SelectionFormula = {$Flags = "pY"}
    Call nc.BuildCollection
    
    ' build list of 1st use masters
    nid = nc.GetFirstNoteId
    Do While nid <> ""
        '-- get the next note ID before removing any notes
        nidNext = nc.GetNextNoteId(nid)
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(nid)
        title = CStr(doc.GetItemValue("$Title")(0))
        Print "Found Private on 1st Use view master, Title: " + title + " nid: " + nid + " LastModified: " + Format$(doc.LastModified, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
        If IsElement(masterViews(title)) Then
            Error 1001, "Multiple Views with the same $Title: " + title + " nids: " + nid + ", " + masterViews(title)
        End If
        masterViews(title) = nid
        nidMasterViews(nid) = title
        nidMasterLastModified(nid) = doc.LastModified ' record master was last modified
        nid = nidNext
    Loop
    
    '-- Create a NoteCollection for Private on 1st Use copies
    Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
    nc.SelectViews = True
    nc.SelectionFormula = {$Flags = "pPYV"}
    Call nc.BuildCollection
    
    '-- remove the user copies of private folders if they were created before the master
    
    nid = nc.GetFirstNoteId
    Do While nid <> ""
        '-- get the next note ID before removing any notes
        nidNext = nc.GetNextNoteId(nid)
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(nid)
        title = CStr(doc.GetItemValue("$Title")(0))
        Print "Found Private on 1st Use view copy, Title: " + title + " nid: " + nid + " Created: " + Format$(doc.Created, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
        If IsElement(masterViews(title)) Then ' does this Private on 1st Use view have a master?
            If doc.Created < nidMasterLastModified(masterViews(title)) Then
                Print "Removing Private on 1st Use view copy with newer master, Title: " + title + " nid: " + nid
                Call doc.RemovePermanently(True)
            End If
        Else ' No, remove it
            Print "Removing Private on 1st Use view copy without a master, Title: " + title + " nid: " + nid
            Call doc.RemovePermanently(True)
        End If
        
        nid = nidNext
    Loop
    Print "Finished Running Private View copy Clean Up"
    Exit Sub
End Sub ' CleanUpPrivateOn1stUseViews
```

This will run for every user opening the db and clean up their views.  If you want to cleanup for all, put the sub in a scheduled (schedule can be never to manually trigger it) agent run on the server, signed by the server so it sees ALL private on 1st use views.  I tested it by shortening my master name (it had a long name which I gathered from the HCL article you should not do for Design cache reasons). AFter refreshing the design of the database, it found the copy with no master (because the name changed) and deleted it.
Detection of a changed master is determined by comparing the Created datetime of the copy to the LastModified datetime of the master.
Copies without a master or created before the master was last changed are deleted. Putting the sub in a ScriptLib allows the agent and dbscript to share the defition.  Caveat: On the server, the output goes to the Domino Log, you may want to adapt. Need to run the agent with elevated authority, see Security properties for the agent.

Comment: Nice to see that Notes/Domino is still in use. I am away since long time.